# Rolling your own custom container docker image: how to create user defined command for local system GPU

Tags: python, performance, docker, tensorflow, gpu

I would like to use my computer GPU to run the program. For that custom container has been created using: https://blog.softwaremill.com/setting-up-tensorflow-with-gpu-acceleration-the-quick-way-add80cd5c988 (please see Rolling your own custom container section). I tried to use ENTRYPOINT["mp"] for creating a user-defined executable command 'mp'. However, there is the following error:

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "mp": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Using mp executable command, I would like to run 'mp train'

Link for my docker file: https://github.com/sandeepsinghsengar/docker-file/blob/main/docker

I have copied the docker file's contents here also.

```
    FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu  
# ^or just latest-gpu-jupyter if you need Jupyter
   WORKDIR /tmp  #my main docker's working directory is /tmp  
# Set desired Python version
   ENV python_version 3.7  
# Install desired Python version (the current TF image is be based on Ubuntu at the moment)
   RUN apt install -y python${python_version}  
# Set default version for root user - modified version of this solution: 
   https://jcutrer.com/linux/upgrade-python37-ubuntu1810  
   RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python 
   /usr/bin/python${python_version} 1  
   RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip  
# Update pip: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing- 
   packages/#ensure-pip-setuptools-and-wheel-are-up-to-date
   RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel  
#RUN apt-get install python-six
# By copying over requirements first, we make sure that Docker will "cache"
# our installed requirements in a dedicated FS layer rather than reinstall
# them on every build
   COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt  
# Install the requirements
   RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt  
   ENTRYPOINT ["mp"]
```

Normal python commands are running under docker. Any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Let me know for further information.

Comment: I read the blog entry you pointed at and am unclear what you are trying to do.  Entrypoint does not define a command it refers to the command to run when the the container is started.   It has to already exist in the container image you built.  It might help if you shared your dockerfile that you used to build your container.

Comment: share it by editing it into your original post vs adding it as comment, etc.

Comment: @LhasaDad I have added the docker file to the question.

Comment: Please replace the URL with the actual contents of the Dockerfile.  Otherwise it's a little hard to tell what you currently have (especially if you resolve your problem and add future commits to your `main` branch that resolve the issue).

Comment: @DavidMaze, I think my docker file is visible on Github. Let me know if there is an issue in accessing. Yeah, I will also try to put it in question. Thanks

Comment: @LhasaDad, any response from your side?

Comment: @Sandeep  Seems my prior response never made it here.   You need to go review the dockerfile syntax.   You are misunderstanding some of how it behaves.   For instance you are looking to have 2.7 installed and your first few lines install 3.7.   Also Entrypoint tells docker what to start when the container starts running, it does not 'name' anything.  Hope this helps.

Comment: so the main point is, how to make 'mp' a user-defined command. Actually, on CPU I am running 'pip install mpunet' to make 'mp' as a command. Where mpunet folder contains setup.py file. However, under the container how to copy mpunet folder, so I can run 'pip install mpunet' under the container. Let me know for further information if needed. Can you share me any other working docker file, so I can have an idea from it?

Comment: @DavidMaze would you like to add something?

Comment: if your trying to copy a file into the docker image you want to use a line like the one described here:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Comment: I have solved this problem. Thanks for your efforts.